# Two dimensional elastic collision of squars

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I am creating mobile game in two dimensional space with only squares. At some point 2 squares will collide together and a want make an elastic collision. That means i need to calculate new velocity for X axis, velocity for Y axis.

[image: There is an image of colliding example]

Here is my class.

```
class Block {
constructor(x, y, vx, vy, e, m){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.edgeSize = e;
    this.mass = m;
   } 
}
```

I already achive one dimension elastic collision with this function

```
    bounce = (other) =>((this.mass-other.mass)/(this.mass+other.mass))*this.vx + ((2*other.mass)/(this.mass+other.mass))*other.vx;
```

I try to modify this function and implement Y axis but nothing work so far.

Also i find this equation at wiki but i dont understand which atrributes should i pass in that equation.
[image]

Can you anyone please help me achive this collison or at least point me torwards now i am just stuck for 3 days?

Comment: It's not helpful to program physics problems without knowing physics.  I'd either get a physics engine to help you or learn more about how to do it yourself.  https://brm.io/matter-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to physical laws, the interaction of two bodies can be seperated on the axes. That is, you can compute the final velocities seperately for both the axes, and you will have the correct velocity.

Comment: Yeah i tought about that but shouldn´t they have different angle after the collison. I mean that if one square has vx =5, vy =0 second has vy=5, vy=0 and after collison i guess first squere now has somethink like vx= 2,5 and vy = 2,5 same for second square?

Comment: They would have different angle after collission, but that would be handled by different velocities in x and y direction. Try it once and you will see why this is true

Comment: Yeah that could work never toguht about it this way i try thanks.